# Python - pass variable into class from a function to change said variable in the function

Tags: python, variables, global-variables

I have some code that's structured like so.

```
def function():
    test = myClass()
    var = 1
    running = True

    while running:
        if var == 1:
            print(1)
            test.update(var)
        if var == 2:
            print(2)

class myClass:
    def update(self, var):
        var = 2
```

Essentially the code should print '1' only once and then print an indefinite number of '2's as the value of var is changed from '1' to '2' in the update method. However, it just prints loads of '1's.

How do you change the value of a variable found in a function by using a class's method in that function?

I've also tried with global variables and it doesn't work (and I've heard is generally frowned upon).

Comment: It won't update the variable from the outer scope. If you want to keep it updated make it a member of the class.

Comment: You cannot pass variables around in Python. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the new value in the update method and assign it in the call to the variable.

```
...
while running:
  if var == 1:
    print(var)
    var = test.update(var)
...

class myClass:
  def update(self, _var): # _var is removable unless you will use it
    return 2
```

Comment: Why bother with the var argument?

Comment: Doesn't was intentionally, the argument var of update can be renamed and if not used as here, can be removed.

Comment: I need the other if statement though, as it contains other code that needs to run.

Comment: @PRyan just replace the `if` statement and `update` method.

Comment: @Julián Esteban Salomón Torres Yep, I'm an idiot. thanks